# How to stop hive from moving data when hive loads files from HDFS into tables?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs

Hive version is `3.1.0` and sql is `LOAD DATA INPATH 'filepath' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE tablename`. `filepath` can refer to a file (in which case Hive will move the file into the table) or it can be a directory (in which case Hive will move all the files within that directory into the table). I hope hive only copies files, not moves to hive warehouse dir, because files are also used elsewhere. What should I do?

Comment: why don't you use `insert overwrite` ?

Comment: Can you give an example in details?

Comment: you may create an external hive table `filepath_table` over the `filepath` and use `insert overwrite table <tablename> select * from <filepath_table>`. although this assumes the `filepath` being a directory, not a single file

Comment: `filepath` is a directory with three different kinds of files.

Answer (score 0):

`LOAD DATA` command moves files. If you want to copy, use one of the above commands:

Use `copyFromLocal` command:

```
 hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal <localsrc> URI
```

or `put` command:

```
 hdfs dfs -put <localsrc> ... <dst>
```

If your files are already in HDFS, alternatively you can create table/partition on top of that directory, specifying `location`, without copying them at all. `ALTER TABLE SET` location also will work.

Comment: I have thought use command `hdfs dfs -cp <src> <dest>`, but there will be two copies of the same file.

Comment: @gnnExplorer  Was it your intention to copy file, not move it? Please explain. Are your initial files in HDFS already?

Comment: Files are already in HDFS, but `filepath` is a directory with three different kinds of files ,I need one kind of them.

Comment: @gnnExplorer " three different kinds of files" - you mean it contains files not only for one particular table? Then the only option is to copy or move files to table location.

Comment: Yes, but I don't want to move files to table location.If I copy files to table location, there will be two copies of the same file.

Comment: @gnnExplorer But you need table location with files only for this one table. Other files in the location will cause error during select. So, having " three different kinds of files" you cannot mount this directory as table location and need to copy them

Comment: Replication means more memory space and time.

Comment: @gnnExplorer you may remove the contents of `filepath` prior to copying. or remove only the file types that you need to replace. need to distinguish those types. ideally it's better to maintain 3 partitions related to each file type in your `tablename`